# Brew installed MacVim with excusively Python3

Tags: macvim, macos

Have installed MacVim using brew on an M1 (ARM) MacOs.

When trying to use [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) extension the next error is shown:

```
[Pymode]: error: Pymode requires vim compiled with +python3 (exclusively). Most of features will be disabled.
```

Is it a preferred way to compile a custom MacVim to achieve that using Brew?

From current MacVim [brew recipe](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/macvim.rb):

```
    system "./configure", "--with-features=huge",
                      "--enable-multibyte",
                      "--enable-perlinterp",
                      "--enable-rubyinterp",
                      "--enable-tclinterp",
                      "--enable-terminal",
                      "--with-tlib=ncurses",
                      "--with-compiledby=Homebrew",
                      "--with-local-dir=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}",
                      "--enable-cscope",
                      "--enable-luainterp",
                      "--with-lua-prefix=#{Formula["lua"].opt_prefix}",
                      "--enable-luainterp",
                      "--enable-python3interp",
                      "--disable-sparkle",
                      "--with-macarchs=#{Hardware::CPU.arch}"
```

Comment: My macvim has +python3/dyn and python/dyn

Comment: As for compiling custom, you have to (learn to) compile the source /shrug

Comment: https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/1064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what I can find:

- [that warning shows up when the following condition is true](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/76df35a8d307b65fb9b5962a678b67317a30b084/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim#L8): `g:pymode_python == 'disable' && g:pymode_warning`
- [`g:pymode_python` is `'disable'`](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/76df35a8d307b65fb9b5962a678b67317a30b084/plugin/pymode.vim#L25) when `!(has("python3") && executable('python3'))`, AKA you don't `has('python3')` (MacVim and regular Vim from brew do) *or* there is no `python3` executable on the `PATH`.

So, double check the following:

```
:echo has('python3') : 'yes' : 'no'
:echo executable('python3') : 'yes' : 'no'
```

If both say yes, you *should **not*** see this warning.

If the former is no, you need to compile vim with python3 support.

If the latter, make sure you have python3 installed with a python3 program. (If your python3 is called `python`, you might get away with a wrapper script or symlink somewhere on your `PATH` with the right name. For example,

```sh
#! /bin/sh
# this file is `python3` somewhere on PATH
# assumes that the program `python` is actually a python3
exec python "$@"
```